# How to upload image to Cloudinary (free) from flutter web?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, flutter-web, cloudinary

I am trying Flutter web and couldn't upload Image to Cloudinary using File format because browser does not support '.path'.
Is there a way to do this?

`the below code didn't work because browsers do not support path.

```
CloudinaryResponse rez = await cloudinary.uploadFile(
          CloudinaryFile.fromFile(image.path, folder: userProvider.user.id),
        );
```

`

Comment: Use https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker Package to upload the file

Comment: @Minato I did pick the file. My problem is uploading it.

Comment: @DagiAle What is the format of data you're getting back from the file picker? Cloudinary can support blob/Base64 so if your image is in this format you can pass it to the uploader too.